# in which memory area method area , string constant pool reside in java 8?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

I have read oracle document but there is nothing given regarding method area and string constant pool. I have doubt that where method area, string constant pool reside in memory in JDK 8 or 8+ .

Answer (score 0):

The java language specification does not specify where this lives.

It also doesn't matter. These objects end up being created, there is no way to directly access them, which doesn't matter.

That's sort of how java works: The spec says what you can and cannot rely on, this gives room to JVM implementations to do whatever they want, so long as they fulfill the contract. "Where in memory..." is a question that in java doesn't matter, you can't manipulate memory directly at all.

Go back to why you think you need to know and find another way; any answer to this question would be specific to some implementation of the JVM, and therefore your code wouldn't be portable. That is, any version update to the JVM, or some alternative JVM implementation such as OpenJ9 rolls along and your code just breaks, probably with a raw core dump. That doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 and later:

- the method area is in metaspace
- the string pool is in the regular heap.

This is *an implementation detail* for Oracle and OpenJDK JVMs.  Other implementations may be different.  But it really doesn't matter where strings and code is stored.  Your application doesn't need to know.

---

By the way, it is called the "string pool", not the "string constant pool".

- All strings are constant in the sense that they are immutable.
- Strings variables that are declared as `static final` (and are constant in *that* sense) are not necessarily in the string pool.
- Not all strings in the string pool are `static final`.
- Not all strings in the string pool are string literals or other compile-time constant values.